# Changing features attributes in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, vector-layer, icon

I am using OpenLayers 5.3.3 and I want to change attributes of the specific feature in my map in OpenLayers. After changing the features I want to the changes to be updated in my map.

```js
this.vectorSource = new VectorSource({
     features: this.iconArr,
     wrapX: false,
});  
this.markerVectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
     source: this.vectorSource,
});

this.map.addLayer(this.markerVectorLayer);
```

Comment: You need first to get the features from a source using vectorSource[.getFeatures()](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#getFeatures) and then use feature[.set()](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Feature-Feature.html#set) to update the attributes.